# Cannot Login with Facebook and Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, xamarin.forms

I am trying to setup Authentication with a Javascript backed Azure Mobile Service. When I call my code to login in I get:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: Error: The Facebook Graph API access token authorization request failed with HTTP status code 400

Here is my code to call my Login:

```cs
public async Task<MobileServiceUser> Authorize(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider, JObject jObject)
{
    return await App.Client.LoginAsync(provider, jObject);
}
```

Is this an issue with a setting in the Facebook app? Or is it something in my code? Or a setting in the configuration of the Azure Mobile service.

Comment: How are you creating the jObject that you're passing to the `LoginAsync` call?

Comment: I just figured it out, that I didn't need to pass the jobject but call it like this:

return await App.Client.LoginAsync(AppDelegate.MainView, provider);